# Mysql replace two value in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**BEFORE**

```
id | cat_id | order
33 |   1    |  1
34 |   1    |  2
```

**AFTER**

```
id | cat_id | order
33 |   1    |  2
34 |   1    |  1
```

Now using 4 query

$db is wrap $mysqli for using placeholder and injection defense

get first record by id

```
$curr = $db->q('SELECT id,order,cat_id FROM `tbl` WHERE id`=? FOR UPDATE',
33)->fetch_assoc();
```

if exist first record find next record by order field

```
if($curr){ 

  $next = $db->q('SELECT id,order FROM `tbl` WHERE `cat_id`=? AND 
  `order`>? ORDER BY `order` LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE',
  $curr['cat_id'],$curr['order']));
```

if exist first and second recorn change order value

```
  if($prev['id']){

    $db->q("UPDATE `tbl` SET `order`=? WHERE `id`=?",$next['order'],$curr['id']);
    $db->q("UPDATE `tbl` SET `order`=? WHERE `id`=?",$curr['order'],$next['id']);
  }
}
```

Important! Checking exist two record, lock rows for update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL [doesn't support update with the same table in the FROM statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause). So because of this there are `(select * from TBL) as t2` in inner subqueries.

Also `EXISTS` condition in the first `CASE WHEN` is to prevent update if the second record doesn't exists ("if exist first and second records change order value")

Here is a [SQLfiddle  example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/503c2/1)

```
UPDATE tbl as t1
SET `order`=
CASE WHEN id = 33 
          and 
      EXISTS (SELECT ID from (select * from TBL) t2  where 
        cat_id=t1.Cat_Id 
        and `order`>t1.`order`
         ORDER BY `order` 
          LIMIT 1) 
      THEN 
        (SELECT `order` from (select * from TBL) t2 where 
        cat_id=t1.Cat_Id 
        and `order`>t1.`order`
         ORDER BY `order` 
          LIMIT 1) 

     WHEN id <>33 THEN
       (SELECT `order` from (select * from TBL) t2 where 
        cat_id=t1.Cat_Id 
        and `order`<t1.`order`
       ORDER BY `order` DESC
       LIMIT 1 ) 
     ELSE `order`

END

where id =33
      or 
      (SELECT ID from (select * from TBL) t2 where 
        cat_id=t1.Cat_Id 
        and `order`<t1.`order`
       ORDER BY `order` DESC
       LIMIT 1) =33
```

Answer (score 1):

With one query it's:

```
UPDATE 
  `tbl` 
SET 
  `order`=CASE 
    WHEN `order`=2 THEN 1 
    WHEN `order`=1 THEN 2 
  END;
WHERE
  `order` IN (1,2)
```

or, for id's condition:

```
UPDATE 
  `tbl` 
SET 
  `order`=CASE 
    WHEN `order`=2 THEN 1 
    WHEN `order`=1 THEN 2 
  END;
WHERE
  id = $id
```

Comment: @ypercube, sorry, was distracted with another SO comment answer and postponed my edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To swap 2 fields by row `id` try:

```
UPDATE `tbl` AS tbl1
    JOIN `tbl` AS tbl2 ON ( tbl1.id = 33 AND tbl2.id = 34 )
SET
    tbl1.order = tbl2.order, tbl2.order = tbl1.order
```

Also you can set your desired value instead of swap between 2 fileds.
If needed, you can add a where clause like below to swap where cat_id are `1` in two rows:

```
WHERE 
    tbl1.cat_id = 1 AND tbl2.cat_id = 1
```

**Update:**
If your order numbers are unique for any `cat_id` you can try this way:

```
UPDATE `tbl` AS tbl1
    JOIN `tbl` AS tbl2 ON ( tbl1.order = 1 AND tbl2.order = 2 )
SET
    tbl1.order = tbl2.order, tbl2.order = tbl1.order
WHERE 
    tbl1.cat_id = 1 AND tbl2.cat_id = 1
```

It works if your order field is `int`, Otherwise you should quote order values in query.

**See the result on** [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8271a/1)

Comment: @ypercube Sure, I don't mean unique index. It is not fill here. For every cat, there is a duplicate order in this case.

Comment: I'll give +1 for the interesting idea and because the update will happen only if there are two rows (with `order` 1 and 2) and no update at all if only one exists.